# OpenLDAP: wait for latest search request of client

Tags: search, request, ldap, wildcard, openldap

We have a customer with an OpenLDAP directory connected to a PostgreSQL. The 3rd Party Phone Client they are using is using the LDAP to search for company-contacts.
While entering the name in the search-field of the client it immediately starts sending the search-request to the OpenLDAP server with nearly every new letter, but not before it received the results of the last search.
This is slowing down the search.

If you search for "someone" then the client is sending this:

- cn=s* -- waits for the result...
- cn=so* -- waits for the result...
- cn=some* -- waits for the result...
- cn=someone* -- waits for the result...

This can take up to 30 seconds until the customer will see the result for his search. The maximum number of results is set to 50 in the client (and the customer doesn't want to change this). And there is no option to delay the search in the client.

So my question is, if there is an option (or middleware, or something) which can force the OpenLDAP Server to wait for the latest search request of a client...

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot force the LDAP server to wait. It doesn't makes sense. The UI is the one that sends requests, too soon or too frequently.
The server receives a request and doesn't know whether there will be another one or not. It just starts processing it and try to return the result as soon as possible.